# Excel walking around

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, cell, move

Is there a way of walking around in a Excel sheet if you have a reference to a cell ?
Like this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cellWalker = mfe.GetMyCell(Mysheet);

cellWalker = cellWalker.GoUpOneRowButKeepColumn();
cellWalker = cellWalker.GoDownOneRowButKeepColumn();
cellWalker = cellWalker.GoLeftOneColumnButKeepRow();
cellWalker = cellWalker.GoRightOneColumnButKeepRow();
```

?

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Range.Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.offset%28v=Office.11%29.aspx#Y0) property will do this for you. E.g.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cellWalker = mfe.GetMyCell(Mysheet);

cellWalker = cellWalker.Offset[-1, 0]; // GoUpOneRowButKeepColumn
cellWalker = cellWalker.Offset[1, 0];  // GoDownOneRowButKeepColumn
cellWalker = cellWalker.Offset[0, -1]; // GoLeftOneColumnButKeepRow
cellWalker = cellWalker.Offset[0, 1];  // GoRightOneColumnButKeepRow
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms281150%28v=Office.11%29.aspx). You can probably implement such functionality yourself by wrapping the Interface within your own object. You can write those methods into the object, then use the Range and Cell properties to navigate the sheet.

Conceptual (untested, but "general gist" example)

```
public class ExcelWalker {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range navigator
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentCells
    Integer currentRow,currentColumn

    public void GoUpOneRowButKeepColumn(){
       currentCells = navigator.Cells(currentRow++,currentColumn);
    }
}
```